# Can I distribute Windows Support Tools with my package?

Tags: .net, licensing, httpcfg.exe

I'm using httpcfg.exe tool from my program. So for the computers that don't have httpcfg in them, can I distribute this tool packaged with my program? Or if I could include Windows Support Tools msi, that would work too, although that would unnecessarily increase the size of my installer.
If you're thinking I should've just read the license for the tools, I couldn't find it mentioned anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Your package is inadequate.  :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked to a lawyer

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution is to use an alternate to httpcfg that is re-distributable.

[Configure a Port with an SSL Certificate w\o using Httpcfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020416/configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate-w-o-using-httpcfg)

Answer (score 0):

I would say no as it is not a redistributable package, you should probably prompt them to go to the official download page if the tool is not detected on their system.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en

although, I can see how this is definitely not a desirable solution. The way Microsoft looks at it, is that it only belongs on a "Genuine" system. So I suppose the argument can be made that if it is a genuine copy of Windows, it is allowed to be installed on that system. I just don't know if by license they would require their check to pass prior to installation.